# Automagic Slug-like links?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I saw a ghpages site that linked to other pages without a .html extension.  Is there a way to get this same link working on my local Jekyll?

Ex.
Root folder:

- index.md
- example.md

`<a href="example">My Example Page</a>`

Answer (score 0):

On github pages you need an `index.html`. With Jekyll, an `index.md`, generated as `index.html` will also work. With `no index.html` generated file, you will have a folder listing as a result.

Did you have some example of repository linking to files with no extensions ?

The only way to get a `http://host.tld/index` link with Jekyll is to set a `[permalink][1]` on page's front matter : eg for index.html `permalink: index/` will generate your page at `http://host.tld/index/index.html` with `http://host.tld/index/` as a shortcut.

The only problem will be that `http://host.tld/` will point to nothing except a folder listing. So, you can live `index.html` alone and put `permalinks` on all other pages.